# how to start selenium standalone server(node js)

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I am new to selenium and trying to install selenium standalone server into my node project. I've npm installed `selenium-standalone` and `webdriverio` packages into my project. now to start the standalone server i was instructed to do `./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install` to fetch the selenium distro and then to `./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone start` to start the server. when i am trying to install the server using `./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install` it says an error with no such directory although i've npm installed selenium-standalone previously? i've also attached screenshot of the error[image]. please help me solve this issue :(